# How to get ABC 12005 from these type of strings ABC000012005 and ABC0000012005?

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm receiving a string which contains values like ABC000012005,ABC0000012005. I want the results as prefix,space and numbers without leading zeros such as ABC 12005, ABC 12005

Comment: Make a start with the development of the code that you want to realize. Update your question the moment you encounter a specific problem that you can not find the solution to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex to split the number and the letters. Then just parse the number as an int. It removes all the 0's at the start.

```
var regexLetters = "[A-Za-z]+";
var regexNumber = /\d+/g;

var string = "ABC0000012005";

var letters = string.match(regexLetters)[0];
var number = parseInt(string.match(regexNumber)[0]);

console.log(letters + " " + number);
```